# Reverse the output of the numbers without touching the for loop

Tags: c++

How to print out the numbers and words from 100 -> 0 rather than 9 -> without touching the for loop? Making another variable is allowed

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int     idx;
    

    for (idx=0; idx<=100; idx++)        // Do not alter this line
    {
        // Add your code within this curly braces
        
        if((idx%3) == 0)
            printf("Fizz\n");
        else if((idx%5) == 0)
            printf("Buzz\n");
        else if((idx%3 && idx%5) == 0)
            printf("FizzBuzz\n");
        else
            printf("%d\n", idx);
       
    }
}
```

Comment: Tip: Put the `int` definition inside your `for`, as in `for (int idx = 0; ...)`.

Comment: Hint: `--` vs. `++`. Adjust your end condition according to how things will *then* end up.

Comment: How would you do it? I won't need to put int cause I've already declared it above

Comment: Elementary arithmetic: if `x` goes from 0 to 10, what does `10 - x` do?

Comment: The reason I'm suggesting putting the `int` declaration inline is that having *less code* is often better. Declaring as close as possible to usage is often ideal, it means less back-tracking to figure out what's going on. In C types are *critical* to understanding how code works. Don't make people work to find out what they are.

Answer (score 3):

Idk why you would want to do this but just do `100-idx`

```cpp
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    int     idx;
    

    for (idx=0; idx<=100; idx++)        // Do not alter this line
    {
        // Add your code within this curly braces
        
        if(((100-idx)%3) == 0)
            printf("Fizz\n");
        else if(((100-idx)%5) == 0)
            printf("Buzz\n");
        else if(((100-idx)%3 && idx%5) == 0)
            printf("FizzBuzz\n");
        else
            printf("%d\n", (100-idx));
       
    }
}
```

Comment: That is certainly one solution, but it increases the complexity of the code when a simpler, obvious solution exists. This is like driving in reverse when turning the car around is a better option.

Comment: I entirely agree... but the question says without touching the for loop. "Idk why you would want to do this".

Comment: That's a...really good point.

Answer (score 0):

The weird exercise.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    int idx;
    for (idx=0; idx<=100; idx++)        
    {
        int temp = idx;
        idx = 100 - idx;
        
        if((idx%3) == 0)
            printf("Fizz\n");
        else if((idx%5) == 0)
            printf("Buzz\n");
        else if((idx%3 && idx%5) == 0)
            printf("FizzBuzz\n");
        else
            printf("%d\n", idx);
       
       idx = temp;
    }
}
```

Comment: The temp variable is a good idea, but ... Just do not use the same variable for the for loop and the if checks. Then the idx does not have two meanings and nothing has to be restored.